# Hello guys, I keep getting this error in android studio bumblebee that I just installed. This is error;

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Could not find method android() for arguments [build_7jwcrzymvpp83e30hia0em3a3$_run_closure2@1a6e8efc] on root project 'My Application 2' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

````
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.1'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdk 33
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'|
    dependenciesInfo {
        includeInApk true
        includeInBundle true
    }
    ndkVersion '25.0.8775105'
}```
````

Comment: Install the Android Studio from this Link : https://developer.android.com/studio, Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 is OLD, As per the date Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 is latest one.

Answer (score 0):

````
android {
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdk 33
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'|
    dependenciesInfo {
        includeInApk true
        includeInBundle true
    }
    ndkVersion '25.0.8775105'
}```
````

this will be in the app level build.gradle file.
I suggest starting a fresh project and choose Compose Activity in the activity selection pane.

Delete the `buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'`  and `ndkVersion '25.0.8775105'`

Comment: i got another error after i tried creating a new project called: Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3